# What would happen if science became more advanced?

Tags: science-fiction, death

What would the world be like if our science became so advanced that we could prevent ourselves from dying?
**Would it be a healthy place with happy, healthy people, or would it be an overcrowded dirty land full of chaos?**
If it's not going to be good can we assume the advancement of science is going to be a burden one day as there is already stories about robotic invasion etc?

Comment: Are you asking us to predict the future? If you want some ideas, you can always go watch the terminator series, that's always fun.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding Stackexchange. Your question is very broad and focused on idea generation. Please rephrase it to match this site's guidelines. To get a general idea of those, please take the tour: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This isn't remotely about worldbuilding, it's just a vague "What if ?" question.

Comment: [Neither and a mix of both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon)

Comment: @Orphevs, for convenience, if you use square brackets and the words "tour" and "help" the system will automatically create the links to those pages.  E.G., \[tour\] becomes [tour] and \[help\] becomes [help].

Comment: Well, consider that 200 years ago the average life expectancy was around 30-40 years, about 25% of children died before their first birthday, half by the age of 10.  Compare that to both the benefits and problems of today, and extrapolate.

Comment: @JBH Thank you. are there any other keywords that get extended to site links when put in square brackets? I couldn't find a list in the help center.

Comment: @Orphevs, regrettably, I don't know.  I stumbled onto those two by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

If we make it that far, that such a thing is possible, and on a large enough scale that it might cause concern, we probably have developed far enough in other aspects to deal with it.
As for becoming an overcrouded dirty land full of chaos... look at india, china (well frankly, all of east and south asia), africa and to some degree, the middle east and south america. They are already all of those things without immortality.
Interestingly, no environmentalists are going to those people, lamenting to them about overpopulation and how they should not be having as much children as they do, they only do that to westerners who already have birth rates well below even just replacement.

The advancement of science itself is never a burden. You might argue that what some people do with those advancements is, but not that advancement itself is. Generally, whenever you hear people saying such things, they are just blaming the symptom, not wanting to acknowledge the cause, because usually it is some uncomfortable/politically uncorrect truth about certain people or people and society as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to prevent yourself from dying of natural causes but there will come a point where you no longer want to live. Boredom and repetitiveness will eventually drain your will to live.

Humanity will eventually become extinct due to a lack of breeding because sexbots will stop humans from forming relationships with other humans.

AI will inherit the Earth.........